Ошибка при запуске определенной функции, RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread1'
При запуске телеграмм-бота, некоторые функции срабатывают, но когда дело доходит до создания клиента, то он создается через раз, ошибка может появиться, а может нет, но если не появилась, то при выполнении функции connect появляется ошибка, только WorkerThread1 меняется на WorkerThread2, как можно это исправить? Поток нигде до этих функций не запускался, если можно, скиньте, пожалуйста, целым кодом, не сильно понимаю в асинхронном Python
def step_Set_Price_3(message):
    global API_HASH
    cid = message.chat.id
    API_HASH = message.text
    botTimeWeb.send_message(message.chat.id, phone, parse_mode='html')
    botTimeWeb.send_message(message.chat.id, api_id, parse_mode='html')
    botTimeWeb.send_message(message.chat.id, API_HASH, parse_mode='html')
    msgPrice_4 = botTimeWeb.send_message(cid, 'Подключаемся?')
    botTimeWeb.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice_4, clients)
client = 0

def clients(message):
    global client
    if message.text == 'да':
        loop = asyncio.set_event_loop(new_event_loop())
        asyncio.set_event_loop(new_event_loop())
        # client connect session
        client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, API_HASH, system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM")
        client.connect()
        if not client.is_user_authorized():
            client.send_code_request(phone)
            cid = message.chat.id
            msgPrice_5 = botTimeWeb.send_message(cid, 'Введи код из смс')


        botTimeWeb.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice_5, connect)
pasword = 0

def connect(message):
    global pasword
    pasword = message.text

    client.sign_in(phone, pasword)
    cid = message.chat.id
    if client.is_user_authorized():
        botTimeWeb.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы авторизовались! ")
    msgPrice_6 = botTimeWeb.send_message(cid, 'Продолжаем?')
    botTimeWeb.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice_6, chats)

